# How can be printed ordered list from number 6 with html only?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

How can be printed ordered list from number 6 with html only (if its not possible how should be done)?

Example:

6.home

7.place

8.etc..

9.etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`start` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#adef-start):

```
<ol start=6>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>place</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

Note that its use is *deprecated* so you shouldn't use it in new documents. The W3C recommends replacing its use by [CSS Counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters).

*(In my humble opinion though, this is partially a mistake, since the number with which a list starts isn't always a pure style choice. Numbered lists carry semantics as well and in this case I consider a number to start with semantics, not style.)*

Comment: However, counting is not content. It's still a styling concern, as most people who are worried about actively attaching a number to something have already done the counting, they instead want to draw attention to the position in a list. Additionally, people tend to STYLE their numbers differently than the content. I think this is still a valid CSS concern. I also trust that the guys who make these decisions have years more experience and they have polled many more than than just you or I on the matter.

Comment: Well, another problem is that I have rarely seen CSS counters in action. IE tended to not support them anyway until version 7 or 8 (probably 8) and many sites just generate numberings server-side.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel ~ And hence there's still support for it, but I think that authors who are looking to use numbering as they do drop-caps will use the CSS styling, and automated generators will either be upgraded or continue to rely on the brute force method for `start=` ~ I don't expect this support to be dropped, altho it's entirely possible rendering engines will on the fly convert `start=` in the future to CSS styling. That may be the best way in the future to handle deprecated tags with direct upgrade portability.

Comment: FYI, the start attribute seems to be back to it's former glory in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element

Comment: @Olly Hodgson ~ But that's just the working draft, so the official status is deprecated. But I'm with @Johannes on this one, would prefer to see it stay in, if only for continued support.

Comment: Well, continued support doesn't bite you in any case. Browser vendors will support HTML 4 just fine, even if HTML 5 is final some day.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way in HTML only is:

```
<ol>
<li value="6">test</li>
<li>This should be 7</li>
</ol>
```

This allows more flexibility since you can reset numbering mid list but it is still deprecated. As Johannes Rössel said you should use CSS methods if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the syntax for

```
<ol start="6">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

However, according to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) the start value is deprecated on OL...

Answer (score 1):

This solution may not look efficient but it works (only in IE).  This way you don't have to use the deprecated start attribute.

CSS code:

```
.hideme { display:inline;}
```

HTML code:

```
<ol id="num">
    <li class="hideme"></li>
    <li class="hideme"></li>
    <li class="hideme"></li>
    <li class="hideme"></li>
    <li class="hideme"></li>    
    <li>home</li>
    <li>place</li>
    <li>etc</li>
    <li>etc</li>
    <li>etc</li>
    <li>..</li>
</ol>
```

Though it works, I feel it's ugly.

Comment: +1 for effort, -1 for not really sticking to anything reasonable... what if you wanted to start your list at 545? You would have a lot of text transferred for no reason ... As already pointed out, it's not quite deprecated, and most browsers have no problem still observing the rule.

Comment: Hi drachenstern,

I agree with your comments. As I pointed out earlier, it's ugly. However, I just want to share the following points with you:

1) This idea can be used from a client-side JS framework (like JQuery). 

2) This approach should not be done at server side and transfer the markup to client side. As this require a lot of text transferred (as correctly pointed by you).

3) This approach should not be done for a long list. (say 545 as mentioned by you).

4) This approach can be used in extreme cases where you have to use the strict doctype for your xhtml.